# Initialize objects with Lombok

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data, lombok

I have the following object:

```
    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class MyComplexObject implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private OuputObject ouput;
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class OuputObject implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private InputObject input;
    }

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public class InputObject implements Serializable {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private List<String> example;
    }
```

When instantiating the object, the object is not initialized "OuputObject" and is always NULL. Why is the OuputObject object and the InputObject object not instantiated or initialized?

When I do a: getInputObject () I get a NullPointerException

(This is an example, it's fake data)

Comment: How about `private OutputObject output = new OutputObject()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@Data` creates getters and setter, `@AllArgsConstructor` creates constructor for all the fields, and `@NoArgsConstructor` creates default constructor. To have your object initialised, you need to use constructor, e.g.

```
MyComplexObject mco = new MyComplexObject(new InputObject());
```

Answer (score 2):

Lombok doesn't initialize properties.
The annotation `@Data` only generates `getters` and `setters` for the class properties and overrides the `toString`, `hashCode` and `equals` method.

```
@Data
public class MyClass {
    private String myString;
}
```

Generates the following code:

```
public class MyClass {
    private String myString;

    public String getMyString() {
        return myString;
    }

    public void setMyString(String myString) {
        this.myString = myString;
    }

    // equals, hashcode, toString
}
```

Have a look at the [documentation](https://projectlombok.org/features/Data)